# react-redux v7.2 withRef is removed. To access the wrapped instance, use a ref on the connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to connect the application with the rest of my components. But I've got this error:

react-redux v7.2 withRef is removed. To access the wrapped instance, use a ref on the connected component

This is my index.js

```
     import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
     import React from 'react';
     import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
     import App from './components/App';
     import reducers from './reducers';
     import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
     import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
     import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
     import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

     import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

     import axios from 'axios';
     window.axios = axios;

     const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

     const store = createStore(reducers,{},middleware);

     ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
       </Provider>,
       document.getElementById('root')
       );

      serviceWorker.unregister();
```

My App.jsx

```
       import React, { Component } from 'react';
       import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
       import './dashboard.css';
       import Header from './Header';
       import LeftMenu from './LeftMenu';
       import MainContainer from './MainContainer';

          class App extends Component {
             render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                      <BrowserRouter>
                         <div>
                          <Header />
                          <LeftMenu />
                          <MainContainer />
                         </div>
                        </BrowserRouter>
                          </div>
                             );
                               }
                                }
                    export default App;
```

And this is my package.json

```
                   {
                    "name": "client",
                     "version": "0.1.0",
                     "private": true,
                         "dependencies": {
                            "@material/react-text-field": "^0.15.0",
                            "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "^3.11.0",
                            "@progress/kendo-react-intl": "^3.11.0",
                            "axios": "^0.18.0",
                            "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
                            "classnames": "^2.2.6",
                            "cuid": "^2.1.8",
                            "custom-select": "^1.1.15",
                            "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.27",
                            "final-form": "^4.18.7",
                            "final-form-arrays": "^3.0.2",
                            "final-form-calculate": "^1.3.1",
                            "globalize": "^1.4.2",
                            "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
                            "moment": "^2.24.0",
                            "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
                            "rc-datetime-picker": "^1.6.1",
                            "react": "^16.13.0",
                            "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
                            "react-charts": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
                            "react-cropper": "^1.3.0",
                            "react-datepicker": "2.5.0",
                            "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
                            "react-datetime-picker": "^2.9.0",
                            "react-datetimepicker": "^2.0.0",
                            "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
                            "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
                            "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
                            "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
                            "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
                            "react-lazyload": "^2.6.5",
                            "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
                            "react-native": "^0.61.5",
                            "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.5.1",
                            "react-native-numberpicker": "0.0.5",
                            "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
                            "react-numeric-input": "^2.2.3",
                            "react-numpad": "^5.0.4",
                            "react-phone-number-input": "^3.0.19",
                            "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1",
                            "react-radio-buttons": "^1.2.2",
                            "react-radio-group": "^3.0.3",
                            "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
                            "react-redux-firebase": "^2.5.0",
                            "react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.4",
                            "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
                            "react-router-v3": "^3.2.1",
                            "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
                            "react-select": "^3.0.8",
                            "react-textfield": "0.0.6",
                            "react-widgets": "^4.4.11",
                            "react-widgets-globalize": "^5.0.20",
                            "react-widgets-moment": "^4.0.27",
                            "react-widgets-moment-localizer": "^1.0.2",
                            "react-widgets-simple-number": "^4.1.23",
                            "redux": "^4.0.5",
                            "redux-auth-wrapper": "^2.1.0",
                            "redux-form": "^7.4.2", //redux-form works with react-redux?
                            "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
                            "revalidate": "^1.2.0",
                            "semantic-ui-react-numberpicker": "0.0.1-b",
                            "textfield": "^1.0.4"
                             },
                            "scripts": {
                            "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
                            "start": "react-scripts start",
                            "build": "react-scripts build",
                            "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
                            "eject": "react-scripts eject",
                            "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy"
                              },
                               "eslintConfig": {
                                       "extends": "react-app"
                                              },
                                             "browserslist": {
                                                 "production": [
                                                      ">0.2%",
                                                      "not dead",
                                                      "not op_mini all"
                                                               ],
                                                       "development": [
                                                         "last 1 chrome version",
                                                         "last 1 firefox version",
                                                         "last 1 safari version"
                                                                     ]
                                                                 },
                                                         "devDependencies": {
                                                             "@types/react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.0",
                                                             "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.4",
                                                             "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
                                                             "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
                                                             "source-map-explorer": "^1.5.0",
                                                             "typescript": "^3.8.3"
                                                                         }
                                                                          }
```

All I want is react-redux v 7.2.0 works with my application. I don't know if I have to update redux form v 7.4.2 to 8.1 or how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, update Redux-Form to the latest version.  The older versions of Redux-Form stopped only worked with React-Redux v5 and earlier.

Comment: and what happens with redux-thunk and axios versions?, doesn't affect?

Comment: Correct, because those have nothing to do with React-Redux.  Redux-Form was only affected because [it was specifically accessing the Redux store via legacy context](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/#the-store-instance-is-passed-down-via-legacy-context), which was never part of our public API to begin with. So, when [we switched to using new context instead](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/#v6-the-store-state-is-passed-down-via-createcontext), that broke.